# Issue loading a class file from another package

Tags: java, class, package, classloader, classnotfoundexception

I have an issue with loading classes via `Class.forName(String className)` when I amtrying to get a class from another package. It keeps throwing a `ClassNotFoundException`, even though I am fully declaring qualified (package) names as the class name.

Is there any way to load classes from another package?

Basically, what I am trying to do is load a bunch of different class files using a configuration. This isn't explicitly necessary (I'm just fooling around with code) but I would like to know if this is possible or not.

As a last note, I am fairly new to code development, having only just begun back in November, with Java as my first language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is totally possible. Two things to check:

1. Use dots as separators: "java.lang.String", not "java/lang/String" or anything else
2. Make sure the other package is loadable -- i.e., it has to be on the JVM's class path.

Comment: If the package is not in a JAR archive, and is in a directory such as `c:\java_stuff\lib\org\bouncycastle\crypto`, make sure `c:\java_stuff\lib` is in your `CLASSPATH` variable. If the package is in a JAR archive, make sure it is found within the `CLASSPATH` variable.

Comment: aye, there are dots as seperators. However, forgive my ignorance, how do i make sure the package is loadable?

edit: its in a jar file, and if it makes a difference, im using eclipse c:

Comment: Ariel has told you about setting the classpath. Refer also the oracle link for [setting the classpath on windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) or [linux](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html)

Comment: alright, so i added all of my packages AND the class files within to my classpath via the "java build path" in the project properties, and the classes still cant be found :\ 

Edit: it might be of use to say that the jar that im using is NOT the main jar, its a plugin system

(im utilizing this in CraftBukkit (minecraft server software))